# Jenkins pipeline - groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-swarm

I am trying to write Pipeline script in Jenkins for that I want to store only image name from Docker Repo but IN Unix cmd the code is working but in pipeline script, I am getting an error like: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: x for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

```
def  Image_name="$(sudo docker images  | grep -e 'hello-world.*latest' | awk -v x=1 '{print $x}')"

echo $Image_name
```

Comment: read this https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation will help you get the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Double quoted strings are interpolated first in groovy. There is no `$x` groovy variable defined and so you are getting this error.

You can use single quotes instead of double quotes or escape the dollar sign as `\$x` in double quoted string.

Comment: I am still not able to store value in a variable  please look into that code  stage ('image name') {
        steps{
            script{  Image_name=sh 'sudo docker images  | grep -e hello/hello_world.*latest|awk -v x=1 {\'print $x\'}'   echo "image name is : ${Image_name}" } } } when i make echo on image_name it print null